# Cron job for database repair and optimization

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, optimization

I would like to repair + optimize my MySQL database once a week!

How could I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mysqloptimize -A
mysqlrepair -A
I run these regularely, the -A option selects all databases

edit:
to run it regularely you would need a cronjob like this:

```
35 0 * * 1 mysqlrepair -A > /dev/null; mysqloptimize -A > /dev/null
```

This cronjob would run at 0:35 AM on every monday morning
If you need to authenticate, yould would use

```
mysqlrepair -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD -A
mysqloptimize -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD -A
```

Answer (score 2):

For repair you can check [auto-repair](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html#option_mysqlcheck_auto-repair) option. For optimization there is no recipe to do it automagicaly but you can try use [mysqltuner.pl](http://mysqltuner.pl/mysqltuner.pl) script and see what it suggests you should tune.

Comment: Awesome, for some reason I was not familiar with `mysqlcheck` command. So a basic command is: `mysqlcheck my_database --auto-repair`